# Bash: set name of directory as a variable while looping

Tags: bash, variables, directory

I have a directory containing a big number of sub-directories within.
I need to loop over all subdiretories and save it names (without a path!) as a distinct variable

```
for d in ${output}/*/
do
   dir_name=${d%*/}
   echo ${dir_name}
done
```

the problem of the current version that it gives me a full path of the directory instead. Here is the result of echo

```
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig992
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig993
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig994
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig995
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig996
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig997
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig998
/Users/gleb/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig999
```

Comment: Try the command `basename`

Comment: You could also use dir_name=${d##*/}

Answer (score 1):

With the `dir_name=${d%*/}`, you remove the trailing `/` only. You will  want to remove everything upto the last `/` as well. Or try `basename`, which is perhapse a better option.

As in:

```
for d in /var/*/ ; do  
    dir_name=${d%/}
    base=$(basename "$d")
    echo "$d $dir_name  ${dir_name##*/} $base"
done
```

which produces:

```
/var/adm/ /var/adm  adm adm
/var/cache/ /var/cache  cache cache
/var/db/ /var/db  db db
/var/empty/ /var/empty  empty empty
/var/games/ /var/games  games games
/var/heimdal/ /var/heimdal  heimdal heimdal
/var/kerberos/ /var/kerberos  kerberos kerberos
/var/lib/ /var/lib  lib lib
/var/lock/ /var/lock  lock lock
/var/log/ /var/log  log log
/var/mail/ /var/mail  mail mail
/var/man/ /var/man  man man
/var/named/ /var/named  named named
/var/netatalk/ /var/netatalk  netatalk netatalk
/var/run/ /var/run  run run
/var/slapt-get/ /var/slapt-get  slapt-get slapt-get
/var/spool/ /var/spool  spool spool
/var/state/ /var/state  state state
/var/tmp/ /var/tmp  tmp tmp
/var/www/ /var/www  www www
/var/yp/ /var/yp  yp yp
```

(on my system).

Answer (score 0):

Can you `cd` to that parent directory?

```
cd ${output}/
lst=( */ )
for d in "${lst[@]}"; do echo "${d*/}"; done
```

If that's not an option, then you can strip it each time.

```
lst=( ${output}/*/ )
for d in "${lst[@]}"; do dir="${d*/}"; echo "${dir##/}"; done
```

As a hybrid, you can sometimes use a trick of changing directory inside a subshell, as the `cd` is local to the subshell and "goes away" when it ends, but so do any assignments.

```
cd /tmp
( cd ${output}/; lst=( */ ); for d in "${lst[@]}"; do echo "${d*/}"; done )
# in /tmp here, lst array does not exist any more...
```